# Hyperlink from Microsoft Word .doc causing Invalid Browser Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, hyperlink, ms-word

I've run into a bug where my website will not allow a user to click a valid hyperlink from a microsoft word document (2010, 2013 tested) and correctly go to the website.

The website is using MVC architectural patterns, so any action such as index, help, etc do not work.

Has anyone ran into this issue, if so, how was it resolved?  I can't seem to find any other issues like this being listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the exact error message - was it "invalid browser error"? Errors like that are usually related to an issue with Internet Explorer trying and failing to handle the URL, even though it may not be your default browser.

See [here](http://techlogon.com/2013/02/04/how-to-fix-a-cannot-download-the-information-you-requested-error-message-on-hyperlinks/) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218153).

Comment: It's website specific.  It just work for the website that I'm working on.  I did look at the two links you mentioned but they don't help my issue.

Comment: I'll need some more info. What was the exact error? What was the website/url that worked? What was the website/url that did not work?

Comment: This fix mentions Outlook, but it also applies to Word so it may be what you're looking for: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310049